Laplace equation in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I am studying partial differential equations, and when I learn the fundamental solutions, the book uses polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the Laplace operator on the unit sphere to get the Laplace equation in polar coordinates. See below:
$$ \Delta u = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{n-1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \Delta_\varphi u, \qquad (1) $$
where $r := |x| \in (0, \infty)$, $\varphi := \frac{x}{|x|} \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x|=1 \}$, $(r,\varphi)$ is called the polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\Delta_\varphi$ is the Laplace operator on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.
I do not know these tools, and according to my searches, there is very little discussion about them on the web. I would like to understand the following questions:

What is the Laplace operator on the unit sphere? Is it defined as $\Delta_\varphi u(x) = \Delta u(x/|x|)$?
How to obtain the equation (1)? I'm not very good at calculations, I've done this several times and each time the results are different and incorrect. I would like to have the details of the procedure.

Thanks very much!

‘I'm not very good at calculations …’’And you’re working through partial differential equations?

The Laplace(-Beltrami) operator on
the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is
\begin{align}
\Delta_\varphi f=\frac 1{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|}\,g^{ij}\, \partial_j\,f\right)
\end{align}
where $|g|$ is the determinant of the metric (in hyperspherical coordinates)
and $g^{ij}$ the inverse metric.
For
$S^2$ you can find the details everywhere.
The hyperspherical coordinates for $S^3$ embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ are
\begin{align*}
z_1&=\cos\varphi\sin\theta\sin\psi\,,\\[2mm]
z_2&=\sin\varphi\sin\theta\sin\psi\,,\\[2mm]
z_3&=\cos\theta\sin\psi\,,\\[2mm]
z_4&=\cos\psi\,,\\[2mm]
\varphi&\in[0,2\pi)\,,\quad\psi,\theta\in(0,\pi)\,.
\end{align*}
And the metric $g$ on $S^3$ and its inverse $g^{-1}$ are
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  & \sin^2\psi & \\  & & \sin^2\psi\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the coordinates are align as $(r,\psi,\theta\,\varphi)\,.$
The inverse metric is
$$
g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}    1  & \\  & \sin^{-2}\psi & \\  & & \sin^{-2}\psi\sin^{-2}\theta\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
